# Rotativa shows square shape on IIS when written in other language (I am using nepali language)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, rotativa

It works fine when I run project. As I publish in IIS, all nepali fonts shows square shape.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this post, as it describes a similar problem, displaying characters as squares, using Chinese with wkhtmltopdf (the main component used by Rotativa to generate the PDF files):
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2886

If you suspect that your problem might come for specific Nepali font, check if the font is installed on server, if possible, it it's not or the problem persists, you could try an alternative adding the font in base64, as suggested in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889154/6235557

Bearing in mind the context you describe, it is hard to diagnose the real problem. If these options do not help you for this case, please provide the code where you use the Nepali fonts, or any other data that could help to undestand the problem a bit deeper.